# Create + Update with custom widget

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created a custom widget that holds "SelecTimeWidget" & "SelectDateWidget"
It works fine when i'm creating a new event but when i turn it into a (UpdateView)

I get an error

```
global name 'to_current_timezone' is not defined
```

I don't know how to go about this to allow the widget to be used in the creation and edit of an event.

```
class EventUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = CreateEvent
    model = Event



class EventCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = CreateEvent
    model = Event

    def form_valid(self, form):
        Event = form.save(commit=False)
        Event.created_by = self.request.user
        Event.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/calendar/')



class CreateEvent(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['title', 'start', 'end', 'description', 'category']
        widgets = {

            'start': SelectDateTimeWidget(date_format= '%m/%m/%Y'),
            'end': SelectDateTimeWidget(date_format= '%d/%m/%Y')
        }
```

The Widget, obviously SelectTimeWidget is also a custom one but the error is leading me to "value = to_current_timezone(value)" this line within the code below

```
class SelectDateTimeWidget(forms.MultiWidget):
    supports_microseconds = False

    def __init__(self, attrs=None, date_format=None, time_format=None):
        widgets = (SelectDateWidget(empty_label=( "Year", "Month", "Day")),
                   SelectTimeWidget(use_seconds=False))
        super(SelectDateTimeWidget, self).__init__(widgets, attrs)

    def decompress(self, value):
        if value:
            value = to_current_timezone(value)
            return [value.date(), value.time().replace(microsecond=0)]
        return [None, None]

    def subwidgets(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if self.is_localized:
            for widget in self.widgets:
                widget.is_localized = self.is_localized
        # value is a list of values, each corresponding to a widget
        # in self.widgets.
        if not isinstance(value, list):
            value = self.decompress(value)
        output = []
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs)
        id_ = final_attrs.get('id')
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            try:
                widget_value = value[i]
            except IndexError:
                widget_value = None
            if id_:
                final_attrs = dict(final_attrs, id='%s_%s' % (id_, i))
            output.append(widget.render(name + '_%s' % i, widget_value, final_attrs))
        return output
```

Does Anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

```
"from django.forms.util import to_current_timezone"
```

I did not realise To_current_timezone was an import, once i found this it worked :)

Love answering my own question after some time worrying about it